# Unable to push migrations to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have a rails app on Heroku. I can connect to it, push builds, and see that it's running.

The problem: I am unable to push builds that include migrations in the db>migrate folder. Any attempt to do so gives me an error of

`` remote: Run `bin/rails db:migrate` to update your database then try again. remote: You have 3 pending migrations: remote:   20210326003113 CreateUsers remote:   20210326004504 CreateAlerts remote:   20210326004819 CreateContacts remote: Waiting for release.... failed. To https://git.heroku.com/*appname* 3dca123..cc0f499  master -> master ``

I ran my migrations locally, committed, tested them locally (they work), then pushed to heroku with the same response as above.

I can run `heroku run bin/rails db:migrate`
which gives me a response of a bunch of warnings.

```
// ♥  heroku run bin/rails db:migrate -a *app name*
Running bin/rails db:migrate on ⬢ *app name*... up, run.1211 (Free)
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.11/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:12: warning: already initialized constant Bundler::RubygemsIntegration::EXT_LOCK
/app/vendor/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:12: warning: previous definition of EXT_LOCK was here
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.11/lib/bundler/version.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant Bundler::VERSION
/app/vendor/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/version.rb:10: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.11/lib/bundler/constants.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant Bundler::WINDOWS
/app/vendor/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/constants.rb:4: warning: previous definition of WINDOWS was here
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.11/lib/bundler/constants.rb:5: warning: already initialized constant Bundler::FREEBSD
/app/vendor/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/constants.rb:5: warning: previous definition of FREEBSD was here
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.11/lib/bundler/constants.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant Bundler::NULL
/app/vendor/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/constants.rb:6: warning: previous definition of NULL was here
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.11/lib/bundler/current_ruby.rb:12: warning: already initialized constant Bundler::CurrentRuby::KNOWN_MINOR_VERSIONS
/app/vendor/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/current_ruby.rb:12: warning: previous definition of KNOWN_MINOR_VERSIONS was here
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.11/lib/bundler/current_ruby.rb:25: warning: already initialized constant Bundler::CurrentRuby::KNOWN_MAJOR_VERSIONS
/app/vendor/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/current_ruby.rb:24: warning: previous definition of KNOWN_MAJOR_VERSIONS was here
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.11/lib/bundler/current_ruby.rb:27: warning: already initialized constant Bundler::CurrentRuby::KNOWN_PLATFORMS
/app/vendor/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/current_ruby.rb:26: warning: previous definition of KNOWN_PLATFORMS was here
```

Checking the logs, it tells me it could not create a user because my user table doesn't exist. User table doesn't exist because there are no migrations. Using `heroku run rake db:migrate`  does nothing because the build on Heroku contains no migrations. I cannot push a build with migrations because it tells me I have pending migrations.

Any assistance with this catch-22 would be lovely. Can readily post the logs if requested.

Comment: have you actually provisioned your database? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#provisioning-heroku-postgres

Comment: Also you can use a release command. If you have a Procfile, it might be trying to start the app/server so adding a release process to the Procfile might help also, `release: bin/rails db:migrate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was inside of my Procfile.
I needed to use `bundle exec rails s`.
Before I was using `release: bin/rails db:migrate`